# Create store Application modifying the Package appxmanifest

Tags: c++, windows-10-universal

I have a universal windows application (Windows run time component) which I am trying to package from:

`Project->Store->Create App Package`

But each time after the packaging is done, I can see my Package.appxmanifest is modified.

I have below extension section in the application node which I can't find after the packaging:

```
<Applications>
  <Applications>
   ...
     <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="AppForUpdaterService.BackGroundUpdaterTask">
          <uap3:AppService Name="com.mhas.appUpdater" uap4:SupportsMultipleInstances="true" />
        </uap:Extension>
    </Extensions>
  </Applications>
</Applications>
```

As a result I am unable to consume the service after packaging it.

It's working when I am deploying from visual studio.

What am i doing wrong here?
My Platform details :

> - Target Platform : Windows 10
> - Target Platform Version : 10.0.14393.0
> - Target Platform Min Version : 10.0.10586.0

Comment: What are the steps after you create app package(there are many options)? After you've created your package,  the appxmanifest file in your project automatically changed? Or you are checking the file from appx package?

Comment: The service app is an windows run-time component. When i am trying to distribute it by creating package from store option i can see the package manigest in the project is changed(only the extension part i added. Its gone). As my packaged service is not working. But it's working when i am deploying from visual studio. This is strange. What is the process to distribute a service app? Packaging or copy paste the dlls?

Answer (score 0):

Well this was strange. When i edit the Package.appxmanifest from xml editor it's gone while packaging from

```
Project->Store->Create App Package
```

But It remains unchanged if edited from the App Manifest Designer ! This may be helpful for someone trying to distribute offline app(Side-loaded Service App).

I think it's a bug in visual studio.